# Bootstrap Tour "Tour is not defined"

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap Tour, and I was working on a simple site to learn how to use Bootstrap Tour. However, there is one error that is causing some confusion. Every time I try to run this code, the console gives me the error "Uncaught Reference Error: Tour is not defined." Can anyone help me explain the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap Tour Test</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Bootstrap Tour CSS -->
    <link href="../TestFolder/bootstrap-tour/build/css/bootstrap-tour.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script>
            var tour = new Tour({
              steps: [
                {
                  element: "#content",
                  title: "Title of my step",
                  content: "Content of my step",
                },
                {
                  element: "#content1",
                  title: "Title of my step",
                  content: "Content of my step",
                }
              ]
            });
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="content">
      Hello, World!
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="content1">
      Another Hello, World!
    </div>

    <!-- <script>
        var tour = new Tour();

        // Add your steps. Not too many, you don't really want to get your users sleepy
        tour.addSteps([{
          element: "#content", // string (jQuery selector) - html element next to which the step popover should be shown
          title: "Title of my step", // string - title of the popover
          content: "Content of my step" // string - content of the popover
        }, {
          element: "#content1",
          title: "Title of my step",
          content: "Content of my step"
        }]);

        // Initialize the tour
        tour.init();

        // Start the tour
        tour.start();
    </script> -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Poopper.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Javascript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Boostrap Tour Javascript -->
    <script src="../TestFolder/bootstrap-tour/build/js/bootstrap-tour.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the link to the library is correct ?

Answer (score 1):

In HTML the  is loaded first before the .

So since your  is inside the , the function is initiated before the js of the imported file is initialized.

One fix would be move the import above the  on the

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Angular 2+ (and bootstrap 4), then you need to add the js and css to your angular.json file. After installing the library (via npm for example). Update the angular.json file.

```
"styles": [..
           ..
          "node_modules/bootstrap-tour/build/css/bootstrap-tour.min.css"
          ],
"scripts": [..
            ..
          "node_modules/bootstrap-tour/build/js/bootstrap-tour.min.js"
        ]
      },
```

Comment: Not sure where you got the idea Angular had anything to do with this at all. It isn't tagged in the question and it isn't in the code samples.

Comment: You are right. I found this question while searching for information on the Bootstrap Tour and though this might be helpful for Angular developers that also come across the question but admittedly did not check the tags. My bad.